# Xcode debug on device failure

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, debugging

The problem is, when I'm debugging my app on device, it doesn't call Exception Breakpoints.
For example, when I debug the following code on simulator

```
NSArray* array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2", nil];
NSLog(@"%@",array[3]);
```

It works fine and stops with the breakpoint and NSRangeException
But when I'm debugging it on device, I see the following 
[image]

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: An exception was raised within `[NSArray objectAtIndex:]`, so what's the issue?

Comment: That code is used just as an example. The issue is Exception Breakpoints not called when I run my app on device

Comment: I'm confused.  What did you mean by "But when I'm debugging it on device, I see the following" then?

Comment: When my app is running on device, and there is an error, It doesn't shown in Exception breakpoint. Is it clear now?

Comment: No, because you go onto show the image of an exception.  It's not clear at all I'm afraid.

Comment: @trojanfoe The image is of an exception, not an exception breakpoint.  An exception breakpoint would show the code the programmer wrote that caused the exception to be thrown (or caught).

Comment: Is there a difference in build settings between device and simulator?  Can't think of what may cause this, but when you go through any differences you may get a clue.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem?  It stopped right where the exception was thrown, inside the call to `objc_exception_throw()`, as the stack trace on the left indicates.  If you drag the slider at the bottom of the debug navigator all the way to the right, you can see the full stack trace.

If you want to see what the exception being thrown is, it's in the first (and only) parameter.  On ARM, the first parameter is passed in the R0 register, so you can see it with this command in the debugger console:

```
(lldb) print-object $r0
```

Or you can just continue in the debugger, and if the exception isn't caught, it'll be printed out to the console.